# lodash: deep merge in objects

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I want to make merge in objects, from this obj:

```
objs = {
  one: { description: "value", amount: 5, value: { description: "value desc", identifier: "some text"} },
  two: { description: "value", amount: 5, value: { description: "value desc", identifier: "some text"} }
}
```

into this obj:

```
objs = {
  one: { original_description: "value", amount: 5, description: "value desc", identifier: "some text" },
  two: { original_description: "value", amount: 5, description: "value desc", identifier: "some text" }
}
```

**UPD:** solution from @ryeballar is working, but I found the problem, "children object" consist the same key name like a parent object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make use of [mapValues()](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues), and have a callback that returns each object with an omitted `value` by using [omit()](https://lodash.com/docs#omit) and [merge()](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) it with that `value` itself.

```js
var objs = {
  one: { description: "value", amount: 5, value: { identifier : "some text"} },
  two: { description: "value", amount: 5, value: { identifier : "some text"} }
};

var result = _.mapValues(objs, i => _(i).omit('value').merge(i.value).value());
               
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.11.2/lodash.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**

In response to your update, you can still make use of the original solution above, with a little bit of tweaking where you use [mapKeys()](https://lodash.com/docs#mapKeys) to transform each object key from a given prefix if it exists from the merge source.

```js
var objs = {
  one: { description: "value", amount: 5, value: { description: "value desc", identifier: "some text"} },
  two: { description: "value", amount: 5, value: { description: "value desc", identifier: "some text"} },
  three: { description: "value", amount: 5, value: null },
  four: { description: "value", amount: 5 }
}

function mergeFromKey(object, mergeKey, prefix) {
  return _.mapValues(object, item => 
    _(item).mapKeys((v, k) => (_.get(item[mergeKey], k)? prefix: '') + k)
    .omit(mergeKey)
    .merge(item[mergeKey])
    .value()
  );
}

var result = mergeFromKey(objs, 'value', 'original_');

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.11.2/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: One more problem( If value = null, this function will be broken, need to add check if item[mergeKey] != null then merge, example of an error: https://jsfiddle.net/88xp1osn/

Comment: @ShootingStar please check the update, I used [_.get()](https://lodash.com/docs#get) inside the [mapKeys()](https://lodash.com/docs#mapKeys) callback.